# Date in java conversion from Redis database

Tags: java, date, datetime, redis

**1** In Entity Class property is

```
private Date date;
```

**2** i called like this from `List<Order>`

```
list.get(0).get("date");
```

How to convert `1387782302827` number to date in java suggestions

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Date date = new Date(1387782302827L*1000);
            System.out.println(date);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`1387782302827` looks like time in millisecond since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT`

```
Date dateInstance = new Date(1387782302827L);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
long milis = 1387782302827L
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(milis);
System.out.println(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like result of date.getTime()
if so you can use new Date(1387782302827l)

Please consult 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)
for details